# Force gradle to use offline version when run emulator for cordova

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I'm trying to create a Android-Cordova app. I downloaded and installed everything it needs, but I'm getting this error.

`cordova run android --emulator
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_172
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`

`Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect`

In every **`gradle-wrapper.properties`** file I replaced this

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`

with this

`distributionUrl=file:///D:/Downloads/Compressed/gradle-5.1.1-bin.zip`

If I replaced the `distributionUrl`, should not the Internet download be avoided?

Comment: when changing `distributionUrl` the download of the wrapper will become mandatory. besides `distributionUrl=file\:///D:/Downloads/Compressed/gradle-5.1.1-bin.zip` would need to be escaped, just alike the other one. just don't use the wrapper for locally installed versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To forget about the escaping and use a correct value, you could set the preferred gradle version using the CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL environment variable.

Comment: How to escape it??

Comment: Just set the url or local file path, no escape, it should work ( I'm using a different remote url on Win10, it should work also for you )

Comment: That solved part of the problem, Now I have problems to build

Comment: Not everyone has the ability to find duplicate issues. When you try to solve a problem you may incur in desperation and more if you are new at the topic. Not everybody has that ability to understand every answer you read.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain myself, I mean, you said that now you have problems when build ( right? ), so I asked if you opened a new thread for this problem, I'll sure give it a check to see if I can help you! :)

Comment: Well, I'm having problems with gradle build and online dependecies. I'm trying to set them offline but I haven't found a solution. See this if you can https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TKduJMdxNa9K0XfbWWi0zg9QiWgvRh3o

Comment: I think you messed up with gradle configuration, try to put this url "http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip" ( without quotes ) as CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL env value, then try build.

If this is not enough try to reset the android platform, cordova platform rm android and cordova platform add android.

Good luck

Comment: I think You've missed the part of avoid internet download. I got low internet. I want to make a complete local build. Besides Google has blocked maven content  to my country

Comment: It's funny to see how people run away from share knowledge like this @sergio-rinaudo when they heard about restriction politics. Obedient to offer a limited knowledge to disadvantaged people.